# Screen fails to draw the second time it is initiated after exit in android (libgdx)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

This is the menuscreen class which when called will draw the menuscreen using the spritebatch passed as a parameter. the problem is that the draw command fails to execute the second time around (i.e after we restart the application) while all other features work perfectly (you can still use the buttons we placed on the screen if we click on the position we placed it in )

```
public class MenuScreen extends Screen
{
    Texture Background,Playgame,Credits;
    Vector2 PlaygamePos,CreditsPos; 
    Rectangle PlaygameRect,CreditsRect,touchRect;

public MenuScreen() 
{
    Background = GameEngine.LoadTexture("Menu/bg.png");
    GameEngine.BackgroundTexture = Background;

    Playgame = GameEngine.LoadTexture("Menu/newgame.png");
    Credits = GameEngine.LoadTexture("Menu/credits.png");

    PlaygamePos = new Vector2(500,300);
    CreditsPos = new Vector2(500,200);

    PlaygameRect = new Rectangle(PlaygamePos.x,PlaygamePos.y,Playgame.getWidth(),Playgame.getHeight());
    CreditsRect = new Rectangle(CreditsPos.x,CreditsPos.y,Credits.getWidth(),Credits.getHeight());
}

@Override
public void Update(OrthographicCamera camera)
{
    if(GameEngine.isBackButton == true)
    {
        GameEngine.isBackButton = false;
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }

    if(GameEngine.isTouched() == true)
    {
        Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
        touchPos = GameEngine.TouchPos(camera);

        touchRect = new Rectangle(touchPos.x,touchPos.y,10,10);

        if(touchRect.overlaps(PlaygameRect))
        {
             SelectScreen = ScreenSelect.GamePlay;
        }
        else if(touchRect.overlaps(CreditsRect))
        {

        }
    }
}

@Override
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) 
{
    spriteBatch.draw(Credits,CreditsPos.x,CreditsPos.y);
    spriteBatch.draw(Playgame,PlaygamePos.x,PlaygamePos.y);
}

@Override
public void Resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void Pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void Dispose()
{

}
```

}

**Even we tried Disposing textures and SpriteBatches none worked!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are running into a mismatch between the lifetime of Java objects (tied to the life of the application process) and the lifetime of texture objects (tied to the life of the OpenGL context which is tied to the visibility of the Activity).  On app "restart", I suspect you're actually just exiting the Activity, and Android is caching the process and starting a new Activity in the same process when you "re-start" the you app.  In this case you'll have a valid Java `Texture` object, but the underlying bytes it "points to" in the OpenGL context are gone (since the OpenGL context is invalidated when the Activity is no longer visible).

The fix is to re-load textures on activity creation.  You can either just make sure all your objects that contain textures (and objects that contain objects that contain textures, etc) are tied to the Activity lifecycle.